# String value not getting modified in a recursion

Tags: c#, string, reference

I am trying to modify a string inside a recursion . Here is the code :-

```
using System;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "abcdc";
        string added = "";
        checkIfPalindrome(s , added);
        Console.WriteLine( added);
    }

    public static void checkIfPalindrome(string s ,  string added)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(added);
        if(s.Length < 2)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(s[0] == s[s.Length -1])
        {           
            checkIfPalindrome(s.Substring(1,s.Length-2) , added);       
        }
        else
        {           
            added = s[0] + added;           
            checkIfPalindrome(s.Substring(1,s.Length-1), added) ;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle for the same :-

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="475" src="https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/u4119h" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I am expecting added to be modified inside recursion and appear as a result outside function call and inside main method, since string is a reference type .But the value of  `added` literal is  an empty string . Although when recursion hits the base case , it has `ba` as value.

Also correct value is reflected when `ref` keyword is used for passing `added`

Is my understanding wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very top, you're assigning a value to the `added` local in your `Main` function. But you're never *changing* that value. You're only ever changing what the argument of `checkIfPalindrome` points to. This has no effect on the local `added` in `Main`, *unless* you pass it by reference - using `ref`.

Reference types have reference semantics, yes. But that doesn't mean that a reference to a reference type has the same property. If you modified the value of `added`, you would get the behaviour you expect - but you only ever replace the argument's reference - pointing it somewhere else. Of course, strings in .NET are immutable, so you can't actually change the *value* of `added` - your only option is to pass the string by reference (or better, make it a return value, which makes for much clearer recursion anyway).

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I verified this with a Class as well and I understand that I am only updating the reference to a reference type . https://dotnetfiddle.net/00aoFi

Answer (score 0):

`string` is a `reference type` but `immutable` which means it cannot be changed after it has been created. Every change to a string will create a new string.

Comment: I verified this with a class as well and it seems I am updating a reference to a reference type and not the actual type . Here is the code https://dotnetfiddle.net/00aoFi